# How to get a match an entire string instead of just parts?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of regexes that I iterate through to find a matching pattern for a string.

I want to get the index of the regex that matches entirely with "00000.00", which is 1. However, the regex of 0 also returns true, but should only return true if there is a digit or string of length 5 or 6.

Meaning, 12345 and 123456 should be is valid, but 12345.0 or 123456.0 should not.

```
List<Regex> regexPatterns = new List<Regex>{
    new Regex(@"\b\d{5,6}\b"),              // 0
    new Regex(@"\b\d{5,6}[.](00)\b")        // 1
}

string text = "00000.00";

for( int i = 0; i < regexPatterns.Count; i++ ) {
    if( regexPatterns.IsMatch(text) ) return i;
}
```

This keeps returning 0 for 00000.00 when I want it to return 1.

** The index has a meaning, so reordering them is a no can do.

Comment: I think your problem here is that the period acts as a word boundry which causes the match to happen on your first expression.  If you can reverse the expressions and test for the longer one first then you should get a match on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `^` and `$` for the beginning and the end of string:

```
List<Regex> regexPatterns = new List<Regex>{
    new Regex(@"^\d{5,6}$"),              // 0
    new Regex(@"^\d{5,6}[.](00)$"),       // 1
}
```

See [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> `^` The match must start at the beginning of the string or line.
>
> `$` The match must occur at the end of the string or before `\n` at the end of the line or string.

Comment: Some explanation would be better, I believe this is the right answer.

Comment: @user3228667 You might be doing something wrong. I just tried and that works.

Comment: @user3228667 Try also adding a \  before the . in the [], as per StuffOfInterests' comment.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be working on my program, but still not highlighting for me on regexr.com. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Oh, just got it to work on the site. Had to erase everything in the text box first. Thanks! You're the best!

Comment: @user3228667 Do you actually want to use word boundaries `\b` or `^$`? In other words, is the number like `1234.00` the entire text or just one word in it?

Answer (score 0):

Being that the period will act as a word boundry your best bet is to scan from the most complex pattern to the simplest.  You could do your for loop decrementing to accomplish this but another way to consider is to use a dictionary of your patterns with the value component being the return value.

```
var patterns = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        { @"\b\d{5,6}\b", 0 },
        { @"\b\d{5,6}[.](00)\b", 1 },
    };

string text = "00000.00";

foreach (var pattern in patterns.Keys)
{
    if (pattern.IsMatch(text))
        return patterns[pattern];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that there is no period in the first one:

```
List<Regex> regexPatterns = new List<Regex>{
    new Regex(@"\d{5,6}[^.]"),              // 0
    new Regex(@"\d{5,6}[.](00)")        // 1
}

string text = "00000.00";

for( int i = 0; i < regexPatterns.Count; i++ ) {
    if( regexPatterns.IsMatch(text) ) return i;
}
```